# Need to sum two columns from two tables, separately, based on products in table 3

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have three tables.
Table 1: Product mapping table,
Table 2: FY12 Sales Numbers,
Table 3: FY13 Sales Numbers.

Basically, I want the end result to be three columns: Product, FY12 Qty, FY13 Qty.

Right now I join the Product Mapping table to the Two Sales tables. If I do this one sales table at a time I get the right numbers. As soon as I try to get the sum from the other table the numbers are all off.

Here is the code that works for getting quantity from one table, but I can't figure out how to get another column in the result that sums the same product groupings from another table.

```
select PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY as PRODUCT_FAMILY,
    PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG as PRODUCT_CONFIG,
    sum(CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.FY13_QUANTITY) as FY13_QUANTITY 
 from PRODUCT_MAPPING PRODUCT_MAPPING,
    CURRENTWEEK_PIPE CURRENTWEEK_PIPE 
 where CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.PRODUCT_ITEM=PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_ITEM
    and PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG is not null
 group by PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY, PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG
 order by PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY ASC, PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

do you try to use subqueries?

> SELECT sum(CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.FY13_QUANTITY), sum(CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.FY12_QUANTITY) From .....
>
> select PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY as PRODUCT_FAMILY,
>       PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG as PRODUCT_CONFIG,
>       (SELECT sum(CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.FY13_QUANTITY), sum(CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.FY12_QUANTITY) From ....... ) as FY13_QUANTITY   from PRODUCT_MAPPING PRODUCT_MAPPING,
>       CURRENTWEEK_PIPE CURRENTWEEK_PIPE   where CURRENTWEEK_PIPE.PRODUCT_ITEM=PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_ITEM
>       and PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG is not null  group by PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY, PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG  order
>   by PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_FAMILY ASC, PRODUCT_MAPPING.PRODUCT_CONFIG
>   ASC